# AdBlock plus hids elements with ids or class with the word "ad"

Tags: html, css, adblock

I have two divs in my site one with id `ad_holder` and another with id `ad_buttons"`

When testing the site on Mozilla with ad block plus installed I noticed that both divs were hidden. On further inspection I noticed it that Adblock was the culprit probably because of the ID names.
I also noticed that Adblock created (or maybe has a ready made) CSS file, that sets the display to hidden.

I know I can fix this by simply changing the IDs or trying to override the Adblock CSS but still need to know if there is yet another alternative way of fixing this, like a small piece of code that tells Adblock it's not a real ad.

The contents of the divs are not real ads, it just holds `.jpeg`s about the client's business.

Comment: For now I've fixed it with changed Ids, just a lil advice I learnt ;)
DO NOT use the word "ad" or related terms in your IDs or Class... :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's better to rename your classes and id's. I would say, that image names, directories also can cause accident disappearing. Solution is to avoid words like:

- ad
- ads
- adv
- advert
- advertisement
- banner
- banners

Comment: I didn't find a list of "undesirable" AdBlock words, so I will try to update this answer with new ones if find.

Comment: Easylist is a common filter list to subscribe to via Adblockplus. [This](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt) is a list of their blocked words, IDs starting with `###`, CSS classes with `##.` Some of them are a bit too broad IMHO but easy to avoid anyways.

Comment: I recently launched a site with the theme name "adwise". Every resource on the entire page got blocked. I removed the D in the name and it worked fine. Annoying though.

Answer (score 1):

List could be found here. Just double check because different on version and software, but i think it cover most of parts.
https://easylist.to/

Comment: Can you please always summarize the contents of resources you link to.