# Shouldn't Adblock be blocking `.banner`?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, banner, adblock

After having read [How to stop adblock plus blocking images in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255493/how-to-stop-adblock-plus-blocking-images-in-html-page) — shouldn't Adblock be blocking [the following JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/AX4Ar/1/embedded/result/)?

I’m trying to design my own banner but am curious if I should avoid actually calling it `.banner`. If so, what are some meaningful alternatives? `.livelihood`? `.bank_account_helper`?

I’m using Adblock Plus 2.6 on Firefox 29.0.1.

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    <p class="product">Will AdBlock block this?</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Not that I've dug through the inner workings of AdBlock, I have named a few divs "banner" when they should really be "masthead" or "navigation" in the past. I run Adblock constantly and never have an issue with naming divs "banner", "ad" or even "ad_space". They always show.

Comment: The linked question is about file names, while your issue is about `class` values. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14079048/1591669) is about `id` values.

Answer (score 0):

Adblock doesn't work with any classes or specified IDs.

Adblock itself has no functionality, in the sense that it does not block anything until you "tell" it what to do by adding filter lists. These filter lists are essentially an extensive set of rules, which tell Adblock Plus which elements of websites to block.

But if we are talking also about the semantics, you should probably use classes like **banner**, **placard**, **sign** or **poster** and a correct ID.

So the answer is:
**No, Adblock should not block the following JsFiddle.**