# My form element disappears when id="..." is added to the tag

Tags: php, html, css

As per the title, )I have a form that needs and `id` beacuse of the `textarea` element. However, just adding the `id` makes the form disappear completely.

**Code before disappearance:**
[image: Code before disappearance]

**View before disappearance:**
[image: View before disappearance]

**Code when `id` is added:**
[image]

**Refreshed page:**
[image]

Does anyone have a clue? I don't even know where to start looking for a solution, this seems so ridiculous. The `newAd` is unique `id` within the scope of the project, not just the page, and is only referenced in code within `textarea`'s `form` attribute.

Comment: Your ad blocker perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079048/adblock-plus-hids-elements-with-ids-or-class-with-the-word-ad

Comment: Woooow... Please, @Luke, make that an answer so I can accept it, cause that fixed it. I cant even... I usually test stuff through unmodded Chrome, but today I'm working on my laptop with a modded Firefox default browser...

Comment: Can you please add code as text, adding images can be difficult if someone wants to try and reproduce your issues.

Comment: @NigelRen Sure, I'll do it in the next few hours.

Comment: It's just something for the future, not worth it for already answered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ad blocker is likely causing the issue, since the id contains the word `ad`.

See this Q/A - [AdBlock plus hids elements with ids or class with the word "ad"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079048/adblock-plus-hids-elements-with-ids-or-class-with-the-word-ad)